# Scraping HTML into CSV

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to extract the contents like side-effects, warning, dosage from the site mentioned in the start urls. The following is my code. The csv file is getting created but nothing is displayed. The output is:

```
before for
[] # it is displaying empty list
after for
```

This is my code:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from medicinelist_sample.items import MedicinelistSampleItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor


class MedSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "med"
    allowed_domains = ["medindia.net"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.medindia.net/doctors/drug_information/home.asp?alpha=z"]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('Zafirlukast.htm',)), callback="parse", follow = True),]

    global Selector

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        fullDesc = hxs.xpath('//div[@class="report-content"]//b/text()')
        final = fullDesc.extract()

        print "before for" # this is just to see if it was printing

        print final
        print "after for"  # this is just to see if it was printing
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `scrapy` spider class's `parse` method should `return item(s)`. With the current code, I do not see any item being returned. An example would be,

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)

    sel = Selector(response)
    item = Item()
    item['id'] = sel.xpath('//td[@id="item_id"]/text()').re(r'ID: (\d+)')
    item['name'] = sel.xpath('//td[@id="item_name"]/text()').extract()
    item['description'] = sel.xpath('//td[@id="item_description"]/text()').extract()
    return item
```

For more information, take a look at the [CrawlSpider example](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example) in the [official scrapy docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Yes i did realise that later to add return item..thank you..but the content which i want is not getting scraped in the csv file..instead all the text in the html code is getting displayed in the csv..how do i get the required content?

Comment: i also wanted to ask that why .xpath() should be used instead of .select() ?...i am using .xpath() but it isn't giving me the right ans :(

Comment: The `.xpath()` & `.select()` depends on the use case. What is the url you are scraping & what do you want to extract from it?

Answer (score 0):

Another problem in your code is that you are overriding the CrawlSpider's *parse* method to implement callback logic. This mustn't be done with CrawlSpiders since the *parse* method is used in its logic.

Ashish Nitin Patil has implicitly noted that already by naming his example function *parse_item*.

What the default implementation of a Crawl Spider's *parse* method basically does is to call the callbacks, that you've specified in the rule definitions; so if you override it, I think your callbacks won't be called at all. See [Scrapy Doc - crawling rules](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.Rule)

Answer (score 0):

I just have experimented a bit with the site that you are crawling. As you would like to extract some data about the medicine (like the name, indications, contraindications, etc.) out the different sites on this domain: Wouldn't  the following or similar XPath expressions fit your needs? I think your current query would give you just the "headers", but the actual info on this site is in the textnodes that follow those bold-rendered headers.

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from Test.items import TestItem

from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Medicine(Item):
    name = Field()
    dosage = Field()
    indications = Field()
    contraindications = Field()
    warnings = Field()

class TestmedSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'testmed'
    allowed_domains = ['http://www.medindia.net/doctors/drug_information/']
    start_urls = ['http://www.http://www.medindia.net/doctors/drug_information/']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'Zafirlukast.htm'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        drug_info = Medicine()

        selector = Selector(response)
        name = selector.xpath(r'''normalize-space(//div[@class="report-content"]//b/text()[contains(., 'Generic Name')]//..//following-sibling::text()[1])''')
        dosage = selector.xpath(r'''normalize-space(//div[@class="report-content"]//b/text()[contains(., 'Dosage')]//..//following-sibling::text()[1])''')
        indications = selector.xpath(r'''normalize-space(//div[@class="report-content"]//b/text()[contains(., 'Why it is prescribed (Indications)')]//..//following-sibling::text()[1])''')
        contraindications = selector.xpath(r'''normalize-space(//div[@class="report-content"]//b/text()[contains(., 'Contraindications')]//..//following-sibling::text()[1])''')
        warnings = selector.xpath(r'''normalize-space(//div[@class="report-content"]//b/text()[contains(., 'Warnings and Precautions')]//..//following-sibling::text()[1])''')

        drug_info['name'] = name.extract()
        drug_info['dosage'] = dosage.extract()
        drug_info['indications'] = indications.extract()
        drug_info['contraindications'] = contraindications.extract()
        drug_info['warnings'] = warnings.extract()

        return drug_info
```

This would give you the following infos:

```
>scrapy parse --spider=testmed --verbose -d 2 -c parse_item --logfile C:\Python27\Scripts\Test\Test\spiders\test.log http://www.medindia.net/doctors/drug_information/Zafirlukast.htm
>>> DEPTH LEVEL: 1 <<<
# Scraped Items  ------------------------------------------------------------
[{'contraindications': [u'Hypersensitivity.'],
  'dosage': [u'Adult- The recommended dose is 20 mg twice daily.'],
  'indications': [u'This medication is an oral leukotriene receptor antagonist (
LTRA), prescribed for asthma. \xa0It blocks the action of certain natural substa
nces that cause swelling and tightening of the airways.'],
  'name': [u'\xa0Zafirlukast'],
  'warnings': [u'Caution should be exercised in patients with history of liver d
isease, mental problems, suicidal thoughts, any allergy, elderly, during pregnan
cy and breastfeeding.']}]
```